# Shareing two internet connections on my laptop running Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, internet, broadband

I have two internet connections, one is internet via our organization's corporate LAN network, and the other one is [mobile broadband via a USB modem](http://www.tataindicom.com/HSIA-photon-usb-personal.aspx)

Is there anyway I can share internet connections and use them simultaneously? I want to use the corporate LAN network for normal browsing and connecting my email client, and I want to use the USB modem for establishing a VPN connection.

- Will I be able to maintain both the
  connections simultaneously?
- Can I have parallel downloads, one using
  our corporate network, and the other
  one using the mobile broadband?
- Will I be able to switch my browser
  between these two connections?

My laptop runs Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two Internet connections coming in via two different adapters, i.e. USB and Ethernet, you could just bridge the two together.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want to be able to choose which connection to use for specific tasks. E.g: for connecting my email client, I need to use the ethernet connection; for connecting to VPN.

Comment: connection specific bridging is another story that I am not too familiar on, but I think it would require some software to specify what packets get used for what applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following method to connect to internet using mobile phone modem:

As you have posted that you have installed your mobile phone modem, it means it is showing in Device Manager. To confirm the type, execute `devmgmt.msc` in Start > Run. In the Modems section your mobile phone modem will be listed. Further right-click on your mobile phone modem and select Properties. Then click Advanced Tab, type the following command in Extra Settings: Extra Initialization Commands:

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","...."
```

Here replace `....` with APN (Access Point Name) - it can be found in your GPRS settings of mobile phone. Open the web browser of your mobile phone and go to Settings, select profile further connection settings select data account edit one of them through which you are able to access web pages on your handset, note the name mentioned in APN section.

It may either be:
1. airtelfun.com
2. airtelgprs.com

Now open the network connection, create a dialer by Clicking "Set up a new connection or network" furthet select "Set up a dial-up connection" and click next. It will ask you to select your modem from the modem list. Select your modem and it will ask you to input the Dial-up phone number - just enter `*99#` or `*99**1*#`. Leave the username and password blank and just click Connect.

It will create the dialer for you - now you can double click the dialer shown in the network connection and click dial - it will show opening port ... `Dialling *99#` or `*99**1#`... connected and network link will be shown connected in taskbar tray.