# How to use two different Internet connections simultaneously in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, internet, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can I route programs to two internet connections simultaneously in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/410483/59659)
>   [Shareing two internet connections on my laptop running Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/69881/shareing-two-internet-connections-on-my-laptop-running-windows-xp)

I am running Windows 7.  I created two Internet connections using two different mobiles as a modem.  I tried to run Internet Explorer and Firefox using the two different Internet connections simultaneously, but it didn't succeed.  I want to use the two different connections simultaneously using two different browsers.

Comment: @ Soandos  I had checked that answer before, however i am not satisfied with the answer.  I want to know if this is possible without using any 3rd party software.

Comment: @torpido If you edit your question to make it clear that you've seen the other question and why the solution there didn't work, then your question is less likely to be closed as a duplicate. I agree that the answers on the other question were not outstanding, so it's fair to ask again, but making sure that we know what you're tried helps get you a better answer ;)

Comment: Torpido, please don't put a space between the @ and the name of the person you wish to address, else the other person won't be notified. cc: @Soandos

Comment: The principle of the answer still holds. It just involves pointing the browsers at two different proxies. those proxies could just be the default gateways of the connections. I think it is still a duplicate.