# Purposely choose Wifi

Tags: vpn, internet

I am using Windows 7. I am connected to LAN via cable as well as I have WiFi networks available.

I connect to VPN through the cabled LAN over internet to other LAN and so my PC will get a local LAN IP from that other LAN.

However at the same time, I want to be able to surf the internet using my browsers using WiFi.

How can I do such a setting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I route programs to two internet connections simultaneously in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/410483/can-i-route-programs-to-two-internet-connections-simultaneously-in-windows-7)